# plsql pass failure back to executing job

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a scheduled job in oracle that runs plsql code.  I will like to be able to mark the scheduled job as failed if scheduled occur within the code, but I have failed with my googling skills.

So

```
if a = b then
return (and get the code to fail)
end if;
```

I assume I am missing something very obvious but cannot find it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but it is not at all clear what you mean by "mark the scheduled job as failed if scheduled occur within the code, ".  Sounds like you may be getting at the EXCEPTION block, and the RAISE command, but you really need to spell it out in more detail.

Comment: If the test is true then the code needs to stop, and the scheduled task STATUS = 'FAILED'  ie not successful which it is if you just return

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help demonstrate:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> --
SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc(p_value number)
  2  as
  3  ex_custom1 exception;
  4  pragma exception_init(ex_custom1,-20001);
  5  ex_custom2 exception;
  6  pragma exception_init(ex_custom2,-20002);
  7  begin
  8    if p_value = 1
  9      then raise_application_error (-20001,'This is custom error 1');
 10    end if;
 11  --
 12    if p_value = 2
 13      then raise_application_error (-20002,'This is custom error 2');
 14    end if;
 15  --
 16    dbms_output.put_line('Non-error completion');
 17  exception
 18    when ex_custom1
 19    then
 20      dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
 21
 22    when ex_custom2
 23    then
 24      dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
 25  end;
 26  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> exec my_proc(1);
ORA-20001: This is custom error 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec my_proc(2);
ORA-20002: This is custom error 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec my_proc(3);
Non-error completion

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> --
SQL> drop procedure my_proc;

Procedure dropped.

SQL> --
SQL> spo off
~
```